# MS Access VBA textbox search and submit

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working on a point of sale program. I have a form with tabs, the main tab is my register part. Right now I have a dependent dropdown box that searches for the product off another table that has all my products listed and after I click add product it automatically adds it to the subform for calculation. I am trying to add a barcode scanner option to this process. I have a textbox that that scanner will submit the product code on it and add it to the subform, just like the dropdowns I have. I having problems looking up the product code on the other table to add it to the subform for calculations. Below is my code

```
Private Sub txtscan_AfterUpdate()
If (txtScan & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblProducts", dbOpenDynaset)
rst.FindFirst "[ProductCode]='" & Me![txtScan] & "'"
If rst.NoMatch Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, no such record '" & txtScan & "' was found.", _
           vbOKOnly + vbInformation
Else
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
Me.sfrmSalesDetail.Form.Requery
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblSalesDetail", dbOpenDynaset)
Forms!frmMain.sfrmSalesDetail.Form.txtProductName.SetFocus
Me.cmdAddProduct.SetFocus
With rst
    .AddNew
    .Fields("SaleID") = Me.txtSaleID
    .Fields("ProdCategoryID") = Me.cboProductCategory
    .Fields("ProductID") = Me.cboProductID
    .Fields("ProductCode") = Me.cboProductID.Column(1)
    .Fields("ProductDesc") = Me.cboProductID.Column(2)
    .Fields("ProdColor") = Me.cboProductID.Column(3)
    .Fields("ProdSize") = Me.cboProductID.Column(4)
    .Fields("UPC") = Me.cboProductID.Column(5)
    .Fields("SalesPrice") = Me.cboProductID.Column(6)
    .Fields("QuantitySold") = 1
    .Fields("ItemExt") = 1 * Me.cboProductID.Column(6)
    .Fields("ItemTotal") = 1 * Me.cboProductID.Column(6)
    .Update
End With

Me.sfrmSalesDetail.Form.Requery
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

Me.sfrmItemsSaleAmount_NonInsurance.Requery
cmdCalculateOrderTotal_Click
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
```

'        Me.Recordset.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    End If
    rst.Close
    txtScan = Null
End Sub

Comment: What is the error? What is not working? Which part of the code do you have issue with? The `rs.FindFirst` / `rs.NoMatch` part?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `DLookUp` or `DCount` of the [Domain aggregate family of functions](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dlookup.php) to do the lookup. No need to open a recordset. Hence, change the `If` logic of conditional to use `DLookup`. Below `Nz()` is used in case a null answer is returned.

```
If Nz(DLookUp("ProductCode", "tblProducts", "ProductCode='" & Me![txtScan] & "'")) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, no such record '" & txtScan & "' was found.", _
           vbOKOnly + vbInformation
Else
...
```

Alternatively, with `DCount`:

```
If Nz(DCount("*", "tblProducts", "ProductCode='" & Me![txtScan] & "'")) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, no such record '" & txtScan & "' was found.", _
           vbOKOnly + vbInformation
Else
...
```